# Daily drip of posts - based on user 'startData' - ordered oldest to newest

Tags: wp-query, loop

I would like to "Drip" lessons for my class - *1 a day*. In the index for the lessons, on the first day, you would see the *first* lesson, and then on the second day, the second and first lesson, etc. - with today's lesson at the top (shown in the diagram).

I'm checking the current user - and finding out what 'team' they are on. that *team* has a `start_date` - and so I can compare the start_date with today's date and get the difference. That's going well.

```
<?php $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'lesson',
  'orderby' => 'post_date', // or date?
  'order'=> 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => daysAvailable(), // difference between today/start date?
  // if there are 100+ lessons... and I only need  5 - 
  // then I should only grab 5 here...
); ?>
```

This gets the other end of the array. I just want the oldest/ lesson-001, 002 etc.

With many combinations of reversing the array - and trying to get only a certain number - it's so slippery! and I always come up with an unexpected span of dates!

I drew up a quick proof of concept here: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/0d0237f0c352a8b42527cdbd4bff9c0e?editors=0011  - but I feel like I'm fighting the framework. So, before I go any further... What do you think? What query options should I be using?

[image]

(just to clarify - those grayed out lessons are never printed to the HTML)

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @SallyCJ - sorry it's such a jumble! Maybe I should split it up into two questions. Let's say I have 30 posts. The student may have started the course 3 days ago - so, they should only see 3 posts. That would mean the oldest three posts. Please see the last diagram. (additionally - I'd like to insert some 'days-off' but that is probably another question.)

Comment: If you just want to display the most recent posts, something like `'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 3` would do it. But if you want the posts starting from the day they *started* the course, you can use date query, e.g.`'date_query' => [ 'after' => '2020-03-22 06:59:59' ]` if the start date was on March 22nd at 7.00am.

Comment: The dates for the posts are relative to the start date / so, they aren't the real dates that they are posted on. Those just serve to keep them in order. I'll check out the date query specifics. Thanks. I've also added a regular PHP example image - in case that helps explain.

Comment: So I can understand what the code is doing, but as I said, for this part: "I just want the oldest/ lesson-001, 002 etc.", you can use the date query to get the posts posted/dated after the start date. As with the 'Sunday'/day-off item, you can conditionally add it when displaying the posts, e.g. after the first post is displayed.

Comment: OK! So, I spent some time with the date_query - and the meta_query - and the 'compare' option - and that is very very helpful!. I'm going to break this into a second question about adding in other objects to the post list, but maybe you can answer the question wih a suggestion that using the query - I can get what I want. : )

Comment: Well, I've posted an answer. I hope I worded it properly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this may not exactly answer the question, but I hope it could help you, particularly with the following part in the question:

> I just want the oldest/ lesson-001, 002 etc.

As I pointed in the comments, if the "lessons"/posts are dated chronologically like in the diagram (Jan 1st, Jan 14th, Feb 1st, etc.), you could just use the *date query* in `WP_Query` and query for posts dated after the `start_date` value and up until *today's date*.

So if for example the `start_date` is `2020-01-01` (i.e. January 1st 2020) and today was February 1st 2020, the following query would return the `January 1st`, `January 14th` and `February 1st` posts, which I *suppose* is what you wanted based on the question:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'lesson',
    'orderby'    => 'date', // Note that 'date' is simply an alias for 'post_date'.
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after'  => '2019-12-31', // this is start_date; equivalent to '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
        'before' => 'tomorrow',   // equivalent to using the value '2020-02-02 00:00:00'
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// ... your code here ...
```

Note: The `after` and `before` parameters in the date query, they both accept a value that [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) accepts (e.g. `tomorrow`, `yesterday`, `+1 month`, etc.). Also, in `WP_Query`, `date` is the default `orderby` value, while `DESC` is the default `order` value.